# How did Lenin secure his regime?

Tags: soviet-union, communism, russian-revolution, lenin, russian-civil-war

As we know, Bolsheviks seemed to overthow Provisional Government easily in November Revolution. Many political parties are inspired and feel like taking over the same way. **War Communism** also contributed widespread economic ruin, and as a result Lenin got a lot of oppositions. However, Lenin overcame those challenges in the end.

**Question: Why and How did Linin keep his position secure? What made Lenin survive? How was Lenin different from the Tsar, who failed in getting rid of his oppositions?**

Comment: This is the subject of entire books. Can you clarify and specify what you find missing (or dubious) from the relevant Wikipedia articles on [the revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Revolution) and [the civil war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Civil_War)?

Comment: Some books just mention how Lenin put down oppositions, but do not explain how Lenin convince people that he is a good man. Is Propaganda so efffective that Lenin's people will support him even if the reality was bad?

Comment: Have you read the articles I supplied above? Putting down resistance doesn't necessarily have to do with convincing people Lenin "is a good man". See also [this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Terror)

Comment: Start by reading "*The Gulag Archipelago*" by Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn.

Comment: Do you mean "How **could** ..." or "How **did** ..."? The former is clearly off topic as a contra-factual investigation. If the latter, please correct your question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good and easy question.

## Lenin won because he was a ruthless opportunist without a shred of consciousness.

#### Ruthless

Lenin did not hesitate to order mass executions and incarceration (in concentration camps) of anyone "tangential" ("прикосновенный") to a counterrevolutionary plot.

#### Opportunist

Lenin did not hesitate to change his policies 180° when they could not be carried out. E.g., the change from War Communism to New Economic Policy or from "Peace Decree" to Brest-Litovsk.

Of course, his enormous personal **charisma** was critical in keeping his followers during such dramatic turns.

#### No compunctions

As Lenin wrote in "State and Revolution", any war conducted by a Communist state is just -- ***by definition***.

He considered whatever he was doing at the moment to be blessed by History and its prophet Marx.

Comment: Ok. But why the Tsar, who also used those strategy, failed?

Comment: The Tsar was bound by traditions, religion, (limited) consciousness, (limited) "civil society" whose acceptance he required &c &c. Basically, he was neither ruthless, nor an opportunist - and could not afford being one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the first comment of Semaphore, and can recommend a book:
Orlando Figes, A people's tragedy. Russian revolution 1891-1924, 1996.
On my opinion, this is the best book on the subject of those which I read. (Most books written by Russian authors are biased in one way or another).